# Serving PNG from jar w/ Jetty, stuck at 100%

Tags: curl, jar, png, jetty

I'm using a jetty resource handler to serve static content out of a jar, and all of my images work fine except for those with transparency layers, which serve, but get stuck at "100%" downloaded.  For instance, if I do a curl, it immediately jumps to 100%, with the full filesize downloaded, but continues to try downloading until it gets to 30 sec, at which point it fails.  Interestingly, the image serves fine when not served from a jar, so I'd think it has to do with some kind of compression.  Anyone see something similar?

Comment: Could you post some code on how you set up the Jetty server?

Comment: " the image serves fine when not served from a jar, so I'd think it has to do with some kind of compression" uh ... what? you mean the jar compression, or the PNG compression ? none makes sense to me.